# Break on property change in Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to find out where a certain property of a certain object gets modified. Due to PHP's highly dynamic nature (`$o->$prop = $val` and such) this is practically impossible to do by simple code analysis. Is there a way to start a debugging session and break at the line where the property gets modified? (Adding a magic `__set` with a conditional `xdebug_break()` call to the class might help in simple cases, but if the class or one of its ancestors already has a magic setter, it can get very complicated, so that's not a good solution either.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the xdebug documentation, it seems like there *should* be a way to break on a variable change.
http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#breakpoints

> watch: break on write of the variable or address defined by the
>   expression argument

But the source code indicates that the documentation is ahead of its actual functionality:
https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/xdebug_handler_dbgp.c#L875

```
if (strcmp(CMD_OPTION('t'), "watch") == 0) {
        RETURN_RESULT(XG(status), XG(reason), XDEBUG_ERROR_BREAKPOINT_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
```

I wasn't actually able to find the string 'watch' anywhere else in the repo, so my assumption is that it's currently unsupported.

There appears to be the bug in Xdebug's bug tracker:

http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=514

Comment: Linked xdebug issue has been closed with resolution "won't fix". I have created new bug report in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75659&thanks=4

Answer (score 9):

Declare the property that you are trying to debug as `private`, and create a `__set` method. Inside of that, you'll be able to find your answer.

```
class subject extends something {
    private $field;

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        if ($key == 'field') {
            debug_print_backtrace(); exit;
        }

        if (method_exists(get_parent_class($this), '__set')) {
            return parent::__set($key, $value);
        }

        return $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Edit: this is another phenomenal reason for getters and setters :)

Comment: As I said at the end of the question, this is very hard if the object already has complicated setter logic of its own. (Granted, 'very hard' is still better than 'impossible'.)

Comment: Not understanding why this is hard? If your object already has a `__set` method, why can't you just check which variable is being `__set` and break if it's what you're looking for? Regardless of what's in there? Maybe if you showed what your magic `__set` method looks like, we could help. Side note: you mentioned magic getters in your question, not magic setters.

Comment: That was a typo (fixed now, thanks). The problem is that the object's setter might itself transform an access to `$o->foo` into an access to `$o::_foo` (or do even much more complicated things than that). Usually I'm running into this problem with framework objects (in this specific case `Zend_Navigation_Page`) which often have very complex initialization logic.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that if the property value is not replaced but modified, that is if the property is an array `$this->arr = []` and you're modifying it, for example `$this->arr[1]=2` then you'll have to put the breakpoint in the `__get` method.