# Is it possible to debug or suspend the program when the value of a property changes in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

Say I have this simple class:

```
class Car {

    public $name;
}
```

[image]

I want to suspend the program when the value of the property/field `name` is set or when it changes. For example:

```
$my_car = new Car();
$my_car->name = 'whatever'; // I want to suspend the program when this happens for evaluation..
```

I tried adding a breakpoint to the gutter but PhpStorm seems to ignore it and continues the execution of the program.

UPDATE: 
I've added a picture for clarification..

Comment: That should work. Do breakpoints elsewhere in that file or code execution path work?

Comment: yes they do!.. for example adding a break point next to when I set the value of `$name` to `whatever` works but  it breaks the program the program right there, if I remove it and keep only the break point next to the field in the class body, phpstorm ignores it and doesn't suspend the program

Comment: @kapreski 1) As far as I'm aware it's not possible: PHP does not generate dedicated code for property access (at the property declaration I meant). 2) *"I tried adding a breakpoint to the gutter but PhpStorm seems to ignore it and continues the execution of the program."* Make your facts right: PhpStorm does NOT execute your program. It's PHP that executes it and debugger extension (e.g. Xdebug or Zend Debugger) that actually provides breakpoints validation/stopping at them. PhpStorm is just a debug client here that displays the stuff and allows to interact with debugger.

Comment: @kapreski The only workaround I can think for you .. is to declare that `$name` field as private instead of public and implement `__get()` & `__set()` methods where you can actually put your breakpoints (as that is the code that will be executed when you try to reach the non-exiting/not-available-from-outside fields.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you for the information and for the suggestion , i'll see if it possible to implement your suggestion as I'm trying to debug wordpress core fields under certain condition

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because has nothing to do with programming. This is a request for a software support.

Comment: This feature not supported by Xdebug. Other workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429074/1461181
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14900928/1461181